# Indexers in PHP

Tags: php, class

I've been messing around with `simplexml_load_file()` function which returns `SimpleXMLElement` and for learning purposes, I tried the *weather.gov* restful services to bring some data and see how it works.

So basically this is what I did:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("http://www.weather.gov/forecasts/xml/sample_products/browser_interface/ndfdXMLclient.php?whichClient=NDFDgen&lat=38.99&lon=-77.01&listLatLon=&lat1=&lon1=&lat2=&lon2=&resolutionSub=&listLat1=&listLon1=&listLat2=&listLon2=&resolutionList=&endPoint1Lat=&endPoint1Lon=&endPoint2Lat=&endPoint2Lon=&listEndPoint1Lat=&listEndPoint1Lon=&listEndPoint2Lat=&listEndPoint2Lon=&zipCodeList=&listZipCodeList=&centerPointLat=&centerPointLon=&distanceLat=&distanceLon=&resolutionSquare=&listCenterPointLat=&listCenterPointLon=&listDistanceLat=&listDistanceLon=&listResolutionSquare=&citiesLevel=&listCitiesLevel=&sector=&gmlListLatLon=&featureType=&requestedTime=&startTime=&endTime=&compType=&propertyName=&product=time-series&begin=2004-01-01T00%3A00%3A00&end=2015-06-10T00%3A00%3A00&maxt=maxt&Submit=Submit");

var_dump($xml);
```

The link belong to `weather.gov` and a rest service.

And now my question comes:

When I dumped the variable something took my attention and I couldn't find a way to describe it to myself.

Here is some piece of the dumped variable:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)[1]
  public '@attributes' => 
    array
      'version' => string '1.0' (length=3)
  public 'head' => 
    object(SimpleXMLElement)[2]
      public 'product' => 
        object(SimpleXMLElement)[4]
          public '@attributes' => 
            array
              ...
```

When I saw public `'@attributes' => array` I thought I could reach the variable typing `$xml->attributes['version']` but I was wrong since I learned this was the correct way `$xml['version']` and I started wonder how it is possible since `$xml` became array here but this code also works fine after running the first code `$xml->head->product->title` which returns the value of the title element defined under `head > product`.

It looks like an indexers like in C#. Basically this is a valid code in c# below:

```
public int this[int index]    // Indexer declaration
{
    // get and set accessors
}
```

But I couldn't think of a way which provides the same functionality in PHP classes.

Can somebody tell me how the '`@attributes'` is called in PHP, an indexer? And how to achieve this functionality in PHP.

Comment: Look up the `ArrayObject` class and `ArrayAccess` interface.

Comment: Instead of writing comment, write it as answer so I can mark it as an answer....right???

Comment: I've made it an answer now :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Objects of classes that inherit from [`ArrayObject`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) and/or implement [`ArrayAccess`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php) (which `ArrayObject` itself implements) can be accessed with indexers. Although `SimpleXMLElement` itself doesn't implement either one (it's probably an internal implementation), you can achieve the same functionality in your own classes using them.

Answer (score 1):

The `@` is an Xpath char. XPath is called by SimpleXML like this: `$xml->xpath()`. For example, if you want to get attribute `srsName` of element `product` it will look somehow (this example is definetly not exact, you need to find something more about xpath) like this:

```
$xml->xpath("product/@srsName");
```